# Texture Bake Problem

Tags: texturing, texture-baking

EDIT: I dont know how make myself more clear. I have a plane in the scene, this plane have 1 material and in this material I have 3 diferent textures painted (1 gras and 2 rock textures). I am trying to bake this textures to make one unique png texture, but every time I hit the bake button the result is a white image. I need to know what I can do to result be like the material in the view port, or what I am doing wrong to the result be this white image.

if I dont make myself clear yet, you can open the attached file and hit the bake button to see the result and see in the view port the way the texture is painted in the object.

I am trying to bake this textures in to one png image, but every time I bake the result is a white image, I see some tutorials but all are in cycles and I am using the blender render, can anyone help me please?

the blender file is in this link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jv5ipxk05k5ilq4/TEXTURE%20BAKE.blend?dl=0

you can open and try to bake to see what is happening if I dont make myself clear..

Comment: Could you please clarify what the problem is exactly? It is not clear what your are trying to do and where it is failing. Please edit your question and provide an explanation or some screenshots of the problem

Comment: from "but all are in cycles" I can understand that you want to bake in internal. Please confirm if true.

Comment: Hi, I am using the blender render, and every time that I try to bake the textures the result is a white image.. I want to bake the textures and result image be like the material are..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big problem is that you have a node material with these textures set up in Blender Render, and trying to bake. Baking in Blender Render doesn't work with nodal materials as far as I have experienced, but that is not a hard thing to fix here. I have a [file for you](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_AVIjamRlEXU0l6MWhUdUhLZm8/view?usp=sharing) to test baking just color to the diffuse in Cycles, and the bake target is a non-connected image node representing the blank image in the 2d editor window. Press bake and you should see it clear and then return a result like you expect.A screen shot for you to see what I did.[image: close up of cycles diffuse at end of chain]

Comment: Hi Craig D Jones, this is exactly what I need \o/\o/\o/\o/, I was making in blender render because the tutorial that I see is with blender render, and I dont know how make in cycles, but thanks your help I can.. thank you so much!!

Comment: You are welcome, I hope someone else can benefit as well. I am glad to see the rgb used as a mask, that is really useful as well.